# Creating Primary Keys on the Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

We have a list of tables in our database with no primary key defined. We have decided to add a `primary key` on it. Most of the tables have an `identity` key column. But in most of the stored procedures, we used other columns for data retrieval. I am confused about in which column I need to create the primary key since it will create a clustered index also.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Read about primary keys. Which columns used for data retrieval has nothing to do with it. (Id columns are often primary keys.)

Comment: The other thing to also remember that make sure you have a PRIMARY KEY on the columns with number.

Comment: So If I create primary key on identity column and Create Non-clustered Index on data retrieval columns, then is it a good approach?

Comment: Having a primary key and having a clustered index have really nothing to do with each other. Primary key is clustered by default, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this following example;

```
ALTER TABLE Db.TableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Id PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id);
```